# When alerting tab.url it alerts undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am pretty new to making google extentions and this is my first. I want to simply get the url of all of the currently opened tabs.

```
function alertOpenedTabs() {
    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
            alert(tab.url);
        });
    });
}
```

I expected it to alert all of my opened tabs' url, but instead it simply alerts 'undefined' a few times. When running `alert(JSON.stringify(tab))` I found a lot of properties, but no 'url'.

Comment: *This property is only present if the extension's manifest includes the "tabs" permission* - Do you have `tabs` permission?

Comment: I do... im quite sure (  "permissions": ["tabs"]) in my JSON file

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.